# Export/Import Screen Layouts

Tags: interface

Just downloaded the latest version of Blender and was hoping for an easy way to port over some screen layouts made in the previous version.

**Here's what worked for me:**

1. Open previous version of Blender
2. Save current state as `startup.blend` (or other filename of choice)
3. Open the startup.blend file in new version of Blender and choose `File -> Save Startup File (Ctrl + U)`

Does anyone know of a better way to import/export screen layouts? Even though this worked for me, it doesn't seem like the best practice since some things may or may not get carried over in a startup.blend file.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the startup.blend file from your old blender config directory to the new one.

Example:
(on most linux distros) `~/.blender/2.69/config/startup.blend` -> `~/.blender/config/startup.blend`.
On Mac OS, it'd be in `~/Library/Application Support/Blender/<version>/config`. Not sure about windows.

The only other things that seem to be there are user-installed add-ons (in `scripts` rather than `config`), bookmarks (`config/bookmarks.txt`) and recently opened files (`recent-files.txt`). You should be able to copy those without an issue.

For the startup blendfile, it's probably a good idea to save your settings after having started up, or to just continue doing it as you wrote in your question, to make sure that the blendfile is actually of the right version. Shouldn't make a big difference what with it still being a blendfile and the great reverse compatibility in blender, but you never know!